# How to properly use a variable in a resource string in extendscript

Tags: user-interface, extendscript, resourcestring

I have the following code to build a UI in ExtendScript:

```
var dlgValues = new Object();
dlgValues.edittext = "string";

var dlg = "dialog {text: 'Teste', alignChildren: 'fill', \
        panel: Panel {orientation: 'column', \
            group: Group {orientation: 'row', \
                et: EditText {text: "+ dlgValues.edittext +", characters: 40} \
            } \
        }\
         \
    }";
var win = new Window(dlg);

win.show();
```

I'm trying to use a variable `dlgValues` to insert a value in a resource string UI but it works only if I use numbers.

For example, `dlgValues.edittext = "string";` returns "NaN" in the EditText box instead of "string".
If it is a number, like `dlgValues.edittext = "3";` everything wotks well.

My qUestion is: How can I use a variable to input string values in an EditText?

I'm not considering to use: win.panel.group.et.text = "string"

Comment: How is this question about Java?

Comment: Java is not the same as Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself, I hope this is useful for someone struggling to find documentation about resource string.

Inside the resource script the variable must be surrounded by apostrophes in order to work with strings:

```
var dlgValues = new Object();
dlgValues.edittext = "string";

var dlg = "dialog {text: 'Test', alignChildren: 'fill', \
        panel: Panel {orientation: 'column', \
            group: Group {orientation: 'row', \
                et: EditText {text: '"+ dlgValues.edittext +"', characters: 40} \
            } \
        }\
         \
    }";
var win = new Window(dlg);

win.show();
```